# Is a relation from a set $A$ to a set $B$ always a proper subset of $A\times B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Is a relation from a set $A$ to a set $B$ always a proper subset of $A\times B$? Or, is it possible that the relation covers the entire set $A\times B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the definition of a relation $R$ between two sets $A$ and $B$ is a subset $R \subseteq A \times B$ so relations are not always a proper subset of $A \times B$.

For example, given $A = \{a,b,c\}$ and $B = \{d,e,f\}$, we have $R = \{(a,d),(a,e),(a,f),(b,d),(b,e),(b,f),(c,d),(c,e),(c,f)\}$ which covers the entire set $A \times B$.

Comment: Ah you are right. I was thinking of a function and not a relation... Thank you for correcting me on this. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 4):

It is entirely valid to have a relation that relates every element of $A$ to every element of $B$.

It can even have fancy properties -- for example if $B$ is a singleton set, the relation $A\times B$ will be a function!

Answer (score 1):

If either $A$ or $B$ are empty, then $A\times B=\varnothing$. In that case there is only one relation between the two sets. The empty relation. And there are certainly no *proper* subsets to $A\times B$.